# Converting Piecewise function into a single expression in MATLAB

Tags: functions, arithmetic, piecewise-continuity

I have a piecewise function. I want to turn this into a single expression. How can this be accomplished IN MATLAB and what  is the  general procedure?

$$f(x,t) = 
\begin{cases}
20e^{-4x^2} & \text{if $0 \leq t \leq T/2,$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $$f(x,t)=20e^{-4x^2}\Theta(T/2-t), t\in (0,\infty)$$
The Heaviside step function is defined as: $\Theta(z\ge 0)=1, \Theta(z<0)=0.$